# Variable in PHP Always Coming Up 0

Tags: php

For some reason, everything else is running fine in my code, but this bit here keeps coming up as zero and I have no idea why. If anyone knows why, I would forever be indebted to them.

Here's the code

```
$marketingRand = rand(0.9,1.2);
```

Seems simple, right? When I echo that very code with this line:

```
echo ' marketing rand'.$marketingRand;
```

I get "marketing rand0" on the next page. This doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't this be cut and dry? Really simple? I've been scratching my head, no solutions seem to be coming from this.

Comment: Read the documentation of `rand`: it returns an integer.

Comment: and applies integers as arguments.

Comment: what Barmar said, also, turn on error reporting next time and the problem/solution will be easily attainable

Comment: @ambe5960 I don't get a warning when I run his code.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get any warnings which is why this confused me. Thanks so much, I'm an idiot. This completely fixed it! I was going so crazy with this that I'm laughing now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand` returns an integer. So it will return either `0` or `1`, not a fraction. To do what you want, multiply the parameters by 10, then divide by 10 to get the fraction you want. Also, `mt_rand()` is generally preferable over `rand()`.

```
$marketingRand = mt_rand(9, 12)/10;
```

Comment: Although, for reasons stated in numerous posts on php.net, as well as on SO, I'd steer clear of rand() and instead use mt_rand().

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mt-rand.php#107738 and 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php#73730

Comment: I'll mark your answer as correct as soon as it lets me!

Comment: @Leprichaun Thanks for the suggestion, I'll use mt_rand.

Comment: @NPersona no problem at all. Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function
    mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();